# Use of Spinner in MIT app Inventor 2

Tags: android, spinner

I am working on MIT- APP INVENTOR 2 for an application. The problem that I am facing is listed below:
I am using two spinner both with choices related to each other in my home screen and a button which goes to a specific screen as per the options selected in both of the above spinner. How can I do this using the blocks of code given to us on the MIT app inventor 2?

HOME SCREEN

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: why the vba tag?